# Wordcount in C that supports singlar letter input

Tags: c, getchar

I have some issues with 'wordcount' counting correctly as it missed singular letter such as  'I'.

Essentially if space between a character/symbol or standalone character/symbol will counts a word count.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int wordcount;
    int ch;
    char lastch = -1;

    wordcount = 0;

    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
        {
            if (!(lastch == ' ' && ch == ' '))
            {
                wordcount++;
            }
        }
        lastch = ch;
    }

    printf("The document contains %d words.", wordcount);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example?

Comment: There isn't any error it just the desire result don't count all words. It will mis count. I have updated and include full code.

Comment: *`if (!(lastch == ' ' && ch == ' '))`* – sure?

Comment: Yep, it just missed "I" or any symbols. It counts any length of characters words with double space without any issue.

Comment: Exhibiting a behavior that you don't want—like failing to count single character words as words—*is* an error. It's not a compilation error or a run-time crash but it's still an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-complicating your conditional tests. If I understand your purpose, the only thing you are concerned with is if `lastch != ' '` and either `(ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')`.

Additionally, `getchar` returns type `int`. Therefore, `ch` should be type `int` to properly detect `EOF` on all systems.

Simplifying with those changes, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int wordcount = 0,
        lastch = 0,     /* just initialize to zero */
        ch;             /* ch should be an int */

    while ((ch = getc (stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (lastch && lastch != ' ' && (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n'))
            wordcount++;
        lastch = ch;
    }
    if (lastch != '\n') /* handle no '\n' on final line */
        wordcount++;

    printf ("The document contains %d %s.\n", 
            wordcount, wordcount != 1 ? "words" : "word");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "     " | ./bin/wordcnt
The document contains 0 words.

$ echo "   t  " | ./bin/wordcnt
The document contains 1 word.

$ echo "   t t  " | ./bin/wordcnt
The document contains 2 words.
```

**Note:** in order to protect against a corner-case of a file not containing a POSIX `eof` (e.g. `'\n'` at the end of the file), you would need to add an additional flag that at least one character was found and check `lastch` in combination after you exit the loop, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int wordcount = 0,
        lastch = 0,     /* just initialize to zero */
        ch,             /* ch should be an int */
        c_exist = 0;    /* flag at least 1 char found */

    while ((ch = getc (stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (lastch && lastch != ' ' && (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n'))
            wordcount++;
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')    /* make sure 1 char found */
            c_exist = 1;
        lastch = ch;
    }
    if (c_exist && lastch != '\n')  /* handle no '\n' on final line */
        wordcount++;

    printf ("The document contains %d %s.\n", 
            wordcount, wordcount != 1 ? "words" : "word");

    return 0;
}
```

**Corner-case Example**

```
$ echo -n "   t" | ./bin/wordcnt
The document contains 1 word.
```